# JavaScript Asynchronous Function Process

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, synchronous

fetchAssets( ) is an async JavaScript function. Could someone please explain to me how the code below works?

```
var x = 5;
this.fetchAssets()
.then(() => {navigate('Auth');})
.catch(error => console.error(`Error while loading: ${error.stack}`));
var y = 6;
```

Does it work like this?:

1: var x = 5 is executed. When that finishes, #2 starts

2: fetchAssets( ) is called

3: var y = 6 is executed

4: Whenever fetchAssets returns, we navigate to 'Auth'.

OR do we wait for fetchAssets( ) to complete before executing `var y = 6`?

Comment: Have you tried running the code and stepping through to find out?

Comment: You've got it right: x is assigned, fetch is begun, y is assigned and the function containing this code returns, all of that immediately.  Some time later, the function passed to `then` is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. Here is a more accurate version:

1. `var x = 5` is executed
2. `fetchAssets()` is called
3. `.then()` is called on the return value of `fetchAssets`
4. `.catch()` is called on the return value of `.then`
5. `var y = 6` is executed
6. Whenever the promise returned by `fetchAssets` is resolved, `navigate()` is called

Especially this part is either wrong or just not expressed very well:

> Whenever fetchAssets returns, we navigate to 'Auth'.

`fetchAssets` returns immediately before the assignment to `y` happens. Functions always return synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is completely correct. You could just test your assumption by adding some `console.log`s and seeing the order in which they log.